# How do I define this C++ constraint?

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, c++20, c++-concepts

I have two types `A` and `A_Input`. An `A` is constructed from an `A_Input`.

I want to define a template class `B` that has two template parameters, `T` and `U`. I then want to define a constraint for `B` that requires that `T` has a constructor that accepts a `U`.

My attempt at writing such a `B` is below:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
requires requires (U u) {
    T::T(u);
}
class B {
public:
    B(){}
    void speak() {
        std::cout << "success!";
    }
};
```

An example `T` is `class A` and the implied `U` is `A_Inputs` provided below:

```
class A_Inputs {
public:
    A_Inputs(){}
};

class A {
public:
    A(A_Inputs ain){}
};
```

I then test everything with the following `main` function:

```
int main() {
    B<A, A_Inputs> b{};
    b.speak();
    return 0;
}
```

This will give

`error C7602: 'B': the associated constraints are not satisfied`

Answer (score 4):

The way to write constructability constraints is to use `constructible_from` concept:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
    requires std::constructible_from<T, U>
class B { ... };
```

Comment: I thought I looked through all of the cppreference concepts. I didn't notice the drop-down menu at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the whole error message, not only one line of it.

[With gcc I get](https://godbolt.org/z/M1Mas98aj):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:31:18: error: template constraint failure for 'template<class T, class U>  requires requires(U u) {(T::T)(u);} class B'
   31 |     B<A, A_Inputs> b{};
      |                  ^
<source>:31:18: note: constraints not satisfied
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class T, class U>  requires requires(U u) {(T::T)(u);} class B [with T = A; U = A_Inputs]':
<source>:31:18:   required from here
<source>:7:7:   required by the constraints of 'template<class T, class U>  requires requires(U u) {(T::T)(u);} class B'
<source>:4:10:   in requirements with 'U u' [with T = A; U = A_Inputs]
<source>:5:9: note: the required expression 'T::T(u)' is invalid
    5 |     T::T(u);
      |     ~~~~^~~
cc1plus: note: set '-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=' to at least 2 for more detail
[...]
```

And more about other errors, that are only due to `B<A, A_Inputs> b{};` not being correct. The important part here is `'T::T(u)'` is not valid. It should be `T(u);`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
requires requires (U u) {
    T(u);
}
class B {
public:
    B(){}
    void speak() {
        std::cout << "success!";
    }
};

class A_Inputs {
public:
    A_Inputs(){}
};

class A {
public:
    A(A_Inputs ain){}
};

class X {
    public:
    X() {}
};

int main() {
    B<A, A_Inputs> b{};
    b.speak();
    B<X, A_Inputs> x{};
}
```

This will only produce an error for  `B<X, A_Inputs> x{};` as expected, because the contraint is not satified.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class Src, class Dest>
concept can_construct  = requires(Src s){
  { Dest(std::forward<Src>(s)); }
}

template<typename T, can_construct<T> U>
class B
```

like that?

You should seek to use named concepts.  That also lets you add static assert tests of them, to catch errors in simpler contexts.

Note that `can_construct<T> U` requires `can_construct<U,T>` - U is "prefixed" into the concept template parameters.